# How to change the global width in Zurb Foundation for Emails?

Tags: email, sass, width, zurb-foundation

I need to change the global-width of the email from the standart 680px to a custom 492px in Zurb Foundation for Emails.

I can't change it in settings.scss, because I need just one email to have this specific width.

The `table.container {492px}` doesn't work correctly.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a new class in `/src/assets/settings.scss`:

```
.tinyemail {
    $global-width: 492px;

    & table.container {
        background: #fefefe;
        width: 492px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        Margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: inherit;
    }
}
```

2) Then create a new layout in `/src/layouts/` called `tinyemail.html` and add a class to `body` tag:

```
<body class="tinyemail">
```

3) Then create a page for the email with custom width and specify a custom layout for at the top of the file like so:

```
---
layout: tinyemail
---
```

This is answer from: https://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/52024-emails-with-different-width

Answer (score 0):

I have been placing custom styles in a new file called *_custom.scss* in the SCSS directory. Then I updated *app.scss* with `@import 'custom';` in the file.

I have been creating new classes and IDs rather than trying to override existing ones.

This is something I have only been doing in one off cases similar to yours.

Hope this helps.